# Exporting $PULSE_SERVER at start up

Tags: audio, environment-variables, pulseaudio, session, flatpak

In order to run flatpak applications (like Discord or Spotify) I currently have to export the `$PUSLE_SERVER` in my `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` like so:

```
export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n/native
```

After reading this [part](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/#index5h3) of the pulse audio FAQ I believe I can get this working by using `~/.config/pulse/client.conf`.

I have tried adding either of the following two lines to my `~/.config/pulse/client.conf`:

```
default-server = unix:/tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n/native
```

And:

```
auto-connect-display = yes
```

NOTE: I tried the second because someone on the IRC suggested that flatpak may be looking at something related to X11 for the `$PULSE_SERVER`.

After trying an `env | grep PULSE` the `$PULSE_SERVER` does not appear to be being set. Furthermore neither of these approaches seem to have any effect (in saying that the first seemed to interfere with the session start as it stopped my `polybar` from starting, I have no idea why or how to debug this).

The main reason for wanting to define the `$PULSE_SERVER` elsewhere is I don't want to have to declare it in each shell and I would like to keep all the pulse config in one place.

I originally tried adding the above export to my `~/.xprofile` (I use [SDDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM) to start my session) however this stopped the pulse folder from being created in `/tmp/`.

Additional Info: I am running void linux with the bspwm window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you could simply export a variable in your shell config, which would get exported each time on start up too by :

```
export PULSE_SERVER="unix:/tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n/native"
```

then after that you could either source your shell config file by say :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or open up a new terminal so as to update the env.

now if you grep for PULSE, then env variable would popup.

Comment: Hey, that is what I am currently doing (as stated at the beginning of the question) this is actually what I am trying to move away from.

Comment: you tried to put it in the pulse config and also in shell configs and you said "env | grep PULSE" was futile. so i just wanted to point out that there is a chance that's because of the common mistake of not restarting terminal/not sourcing the corresponding file.

Comment: I have said that my current solution is to have it in my `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` and this is what I would like to move away from, sorry when I was referring to `env | grep PULSE` I meant it was futile when using the other methods.